# Search filter to show results on search page for custom post type

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a filter that has `select` options for `Wheel base` and `price`. `Wheel base` is a `custom taxonomy` assigned to the `vehicles` post type. This taxonomy has two options `SWB` and `LWB`.

**Here is the markup for my form**:

```html
<form class="filterOffers__form" role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/search'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">

  <fieldset class="filterOffers__fieldset filterOffers__wheelbase">
    <select class="filterOffers__select">
      <option value="">Wheel base</option>
      <option value="swb">Short wheel base</option>
      <option value="lwb">Long wheel base</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="filterOffers__fieldset filterOffers__minprice">
    <select class="filterOffers__select" name="min-price">
      <option value="">Min £ price</option>
      <option value="5000">£5000</option>
      <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
      <option value="20000">£20,000</option>
      <option value="30000">£30,000</option>
      <option value="40000">£40,000</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="filterOffers__fieldset filterOffers__maxprice">
    <select class="filterOffers__select" name="max-price">
      <option value="">Max £ price</option>
      <option value="10000">£10,000</option>
      <option value="20000">£20,000</option>
      <option value="30000">£30,000</option>
      <option value="40000">£40,000</option>
      <option value="50000">£50,000</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="filterOffers__fieldset d-none">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="vehicles" />
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset class="filterOffers__fieldset">
    <input class="filterOffers__submit" type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" />
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

When the `search` button is clicked, I want to search the `vehicles` post type and display those vehicles that match the filtered query. For example, if I have `Short wheel base` and `£5000 - £10,000` selected form the dropdowns, I want to display all the `vehicles` that match that query.

To do this, I have created a `search.php` file, which looks like this:

```html
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Search Page
*/

get_header();

  global $query_string;

  $query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
  $search_query = array();

  foreach ($query_args as $key => $string){
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
  }

  $the_query = new wp_query($search_query);

  if( $the_query -> have_posts() ) : ?>
    <h3>Search Result for : <?php echo htmlentities($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </h3>

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
      echo the_title();
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

  else: ?>

    <h2><?php _e("no posts found"); ?></h2>

  <?php endif;

get_footer(); ?>
```

**Current behaviour:**

If from the dropdown I select `Short wheel base` and `£5000 - £10,000` and click the search button, it takes me to:

`/search?wheel-base=swb&min-price=5000-10000&max-price=&post_type=vehicles`

The above url is correct based on my search parameters. However, the page 404s.

- When I'm on `/search`, it'll `echo` the "Search Result for :" text.
- When I'm on `/search?wheel-base=swb&min-price=5000-10000&max-price=&post_type=vehicles` - it'll 404.

I have followed the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) to create a search page (a page for search exists in the admin with the URL `/search` and the search page template is applied).

Ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: I don't know well wordpress, have you any middleware wich can return a 404 in case of error ? if you're not authenticated for example ?

Comment: @Ruvee - Unfortunately no, adding the trailing slash (`/search/?`) still results in a `404`

Comment: @mbesson - No, no plugins or such have been added that mess with permalinks or authentication

Comment: It's true that `post_type` (as well as `s`) is a reserved term or query var name, but you really should not make the custom `WP_Query` in your `search.php` template - it should just display the *main loop* (or the posts that already retrieved from the database via the main query - the global `$wp_query`) without having to make that custom query. You can check [the Twenty Twenty-One theme](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwentyone/1.3/search.php) to see an example of a good Search **Results** template.

Comment: And if you wish to have a custom search page at `/search/` (which is a Page - post type `page`), then you should use a template with another name like `template-search.php`, and then re-select the template from the Template dropdown on the Pages admin page.

Comment: On the Wordpress Codex page that you followed says `Note: The filename search.php is reserved as a special template name, so avoid its usage; the suggested searchpage.php just makes it easy to recognize in the list of files.`.

After you change your file from `search.php` to `something-else.php` don't forget to login into your dashboard and create a new page and choose *Search Page* from the `Page Attribute -> Template` section.

So basically your `something-else.php` file is just a template not a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this post : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/291661/205128

`post_type` appears to be a reserved name in wordpress ([list](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms))

Can you try to change `post_type` input name, or prefix it like `mynamespace_post_type` ?